# Cast TimeStamp so like could be used

Tags: delphi, firebird

Can somebody please tell me how timestamp can be casted in Firebird in a way it can be later then used in like statement. Line statement will only search in date part of timestamp so i gues it could first cast to date and then to varchar(10).

I got this, but it doesn't work right

```
SELECT t.createdon
FROM wstaskinstance t
WHERE CAST(CAST (t.createdon AS DATE) AS VARCHAR(10)) LIKE :Date
```

Comment: It seems strange to use `LIKE` with date / timestamp... what do you want to achieve? I'd quess what you want to use is `BETWEEN` or just compare your date against two other dates (ie start and end date of a date range).

Comment: @ain I try to create filter on column. On column date I show TimeStamp but filter(Search) below column name would only search in date. I would use like because then i can search like in any other text column and wouldn't need to extra lines in method when I filter records.

Comment: What are the conditions you want to use - IOW what the 'regexp' part of the LIKE looks like? Do you wan't to filter records belonging to specific date range or might it be like "all mondays", "all 21st days in any month", etc?

Comment: @ain I would like to get for example if i type 20 in filter I would like to get all dates that includes any 11. day in month OR dates in 2011, 1911, 2110... OR all days in all years that where month is November

Comment: `LIKE` only works with character types, and it's inappropriate to use with any other types. You should be using a different comparison, such as `BETWEEN` or `>=` or `<=`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to return all dates of all years use **CONTAINING** instead. For example if you pass '11-20' as :date parameter, it will return all dates of all years that contains (2001-11-20,2004-11-20, 2015-11-20...).

```
SELECT t.createdon
FROM wstaskinstance t
WHERE CAST(CAST (t.createdon AS DATE) AS VARCHAR(10)) 
CONTAINING :Date
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you type something in the filter and then set is in `:Date` parameter. Then your query should be edited like this:

```
SELECT t.createdon
FROM wstaskinstance t
WHERE CAST(CAST (t.createdon AS DATE) AS VARCHAR(10)) LIKE ('%'||:Date||'%')
```